# How to hide/display the ports in custom element using jointjs?

Tags: jquery, jointjs

Need to attach hover effect on the ports of custm htm elements by using jointjs.ie the red port should display when we move move in to the red port else it should hide. Tried in google but culdn't find out solution. Please suggest any other common or alternative solution.
[image]